# time stamp on status change

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a macro which give the timestamp on status change but unfortunately I am unsuccessful so far. Can anybody help me in this regard.
Mentioned below are the status in my project.
clearing
wait for start
ongoing
on hold
closed
finalisiert
prämiert
leer
in Umsetzung

The main reason of extrating the date is to calculate the number of days for a particular status.

Thanks in advance

EDIT updated question to include code:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo Fìn
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Columns(1))
        If LCase(rng.Value) = "clearing" Then
            Cells(rng.Row, 2) = Date
            Cells(rng.Row, 2).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
            'Cells(rng.Row, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "maybe put the formula in here"
        ElseIf rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = "true" Then
            Cells(rng.Row, 4) = Date
            Cells(rng.Row, 4).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"



      Else
      If LCase(rng.Value) = "wait for start" Then
            Cells(rng.Row, 6) = Date
            Cells(rng.Row, 6).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
            'Cells(rng.Row, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "maybe put the formula in here"
        ElseIf rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = 2 Then
            Cells(rng.Row, 8) = Date
            Cells(rng.Row, 8).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
        End If
        End If
    Next rng
End If
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I have above mentioned Code but actually it is not fulfulling my requirement. Status change means: there are almost 6 status in my project and whenever for example I change the status from wait for start to ongoing it should return a start date for the status wait for start and end date for the same status so that I can calculate the number of days.

Comment: Also what do you mean by status change? What status is changing?

Comment: Please edit your question for better readability (especially status) and add the code that you have already built even if it doesn't work. If it doesn't work, tell us which error it gave you and on which line.

Comment: So when you start the code you want to find out what time a 'status' changes to another? What is the code that makes the 'status' change?

Comment: i have mentioned the code below @Sam

Comment: To me that code just looks to see if the value of some cells are set to a status. Correct me if I am wrong though. But how do the cells actually get the status? So when does a cell value change to be "Clearing" etc?

Comment: that i have to do manually. there is one column of stauts with differnet value for example 1.clearing 2.wait for start 3.ongoing 4.on hold 5.closed 6.finalisiert 7.prämiert 8.leer 9.in Umsetzung

Comment: If that is done manually. Could you then put your code in worksheet_change? Then you would change your code to be what ever cell just changed get the column you want to put the time-stamp in and then do the cell value to be a timestamp.

Comment: I have put the code in worksheet_change. I mentioned the idea of why i wanted to do that. but still i didnot got any postive response

Comment: Did any timestamp show up? Do you want a time stamp for any changes of status? I can a mock code that may be better than your code if you like. Would need to know what column the status is in that changes. And where you want the timestamp

Comment: For the change in status I have created a timestamp it is easy but the main issue is I need the end date for that particular status.

Comment: What would the end date be? How is it worked out?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, less confusing....

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If LCase(Target) = "clearing" Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yy")
    If LCase(Target) = "true" Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yy")
    '==========2 conditions==============
    If LCase(Target) = "something" And LCase(Target.Offset(0, 1)) = "maybe" Then
        MsgBox "Example with 2 conditions"
        Target.Offset(0, 4) = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yy")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can somebody explains me what does rng.Offset(0, 2) means?

Comment: rng.offset is just how far from the range do you want the data to be. So in this case rng.offset(0,2) would be the same row as it is 0. And 2 columns away.

Comment: is there a possibility to send the excel sheer via this website?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You would have to upload it somewhere and then provide a link to it

Comment: I want to send it to you so that you can have a look on that, to have an idea what is the requirement

Comment: Upload an example workbook to a cloud, such as google drive or some other upload service, then attach a link to your post. Don't say something doesn't work if you don't know what is going on. I wouldn't give you a code that doesn't work.

Comment: I have attached the file for reference. This is actually i am planning to create which unfortunately was not successful. One row refers to one project and the status can be change depending on the project.

Comment: The code supplied earlier will give you the tools you require to do what you need. Target is the cell you have changed,`target.offset(0,1)` is one cell over from the changed target. as is `target.offset(0,6)` would be 6 cells over from the target. You have to make sure that whatever is in your dropdown menu matches in your code exactly. So `    If LCase(Target) = "wait for start" Then Target.Offset(0, 4) = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yy")` will put the date in Column "F" if you change a cell in Column A to "wait for start"

Comment: Thanks guys for the support. The first step is just working fine. I am unable to get the start date for every start. now the second step which is relatively difficult,to get the end date of stauts when is changed. for example when i changed the stauts from ongoing to closed it should give me the end date from ongoing